# Symfony Match Route with Multiple Hosts

Tags: symfony

I know it is possible to filter a route by host, like this:

```
irc_backend.report.stacking_issue:
    path: /reports/stacking-issues
    host: backend.domain.com
    defaults:  { _controller: IRCBackendBundle:Reports/Product/StackingIssueReport:index }
```

Is it possible to alter this configuration to match multiple domains? For example:

```
irc_backend.report.stacking_issue:
    path: /reports/stacking-issues
    host: backend.domain.com|dev.backend.domain.com
    defaults:  { _controller: IRCBackendBundle:Reports/Product/StackingIssueReport:index }
```

I'm trying to avoid setting up 2 routes for every page.

Comment: Did you try placeholders in your hostname with requirements?

Answer (score 5):

You can try placeholders in your hostname with requirements (i.e.. [Symfony Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html))

```
irc_backend.report.stacking_issue:
    path: /reports/stacking-issues
    host: "{mydomaines}"
    defaults:  { _controller: IRCBackendBundle:Reports/Product/StackingIssueReport:index }
    requirements:
        mydomaines: backend.domain.com|dev.backend.domain.com
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that every time I generate a URL using the router, I have to specify which subdomain to use.  I was hoping to avoid having to pass in the current subdomain everytime I get a url from the router.

Answer (score 3):

If you read the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html), you'd know that you need to use placeholders. For your code, it would be :

```
irc_backend.report.stacking_issue:
    path: /reports/stacking-issues
    host: "{subdomain}.domain.com"
    defaults:
        _controller: IRCBackendBundle:Reports/Product/StackingIssueReport:index 
        subdomain: backend
    requirements:
        subdomain: backend|dev.backend
```

I hope it'll help you !

EDIT :

If you want your default subdomain to be the current one, you can use a parameter like this :

```
irc_backend.report.stacking_issue:
    path: /reports/stacking-issues
    host: "{subdomain}.domain.com"
    defaults:
        _controller: IRCBackendBundle:Reports/Product/StackingIssueReport:index 
        subdomain: "%subdomain%"
    requirements:
        subdomain: backend|dev.backend
```

Then you will be able to define this parameter in an [Event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) with this line of code :

```
$container->setParameter("subdomain", $your_subdomain);
```

P-S : Don't forget to add the Service container to your listener's dependencies

Comment: The problem with this approach is that every time I generate a URL using the router, I have to specify which subdomain to use.  I was hoping to avoid having to pass in the current subdomain everytime I get a url from the router.

Comment: Take a look at my EDIT

Comment: It turns out that you cannot set a container parameter in a listener like this, because you will receive this error: "Impossible to call set() on a frozen ParameterBag."