# Symfony direct a subdomain to a route

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, symfony-2.8

I have a Symfony project hosted in a.example.com. In it, let's say a.example.com/site2 must be accessible through b.example.com. Simply put when I access b.example.com from the browser it must load a.example.com/site2 without showing a.example.com/site2 in the address bar (not redirecting). Is there a way to do this? Is this doable through htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the 'host' property in your routing.yml as follow

```
acme_hello:
    resource: "@AcmeHelloBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    host:     "hello.example.com"
    path:     "your path action in the controller"
```

Link : http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/routing/hostname_pattern.html

Comment: Is this the "app/config/routing.yml" ??

Comment: This is not working. I get "No route found for "GET /test"

Comment: Can you share your app/config/config.yml and app/config/routing.yml ?

Comment: and for more info this is a duplicate question : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211715/symfony-match-route-with-multiple-hosts](duplicated)